# how to create numbers(images) in twitter format?

Tags: iphone

I am developing a list of buttons for a puzzle game where i want to place images on these buttons with good texture on it like what we see just like in twitter format.is it possible to do this? if so how?

Thanks,

Comment: What's "Twitter format"?

Answer (score 1):

UIButton allows you to set the background for a button

[myButton setBackgroundImage:myUIImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

however, its not clear from your question if you really mean a button, or what a twitter format is!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.
Here my question is not setting the background image but it is like this....
creating the images in "Twitter Format" means the text format what we see int twitter.com, I want to know weather is it possible to create images with numbers in that particular format just as we see in twitter site.

Comment: I'm still none the wiser. Can you make a screengrab of what you are after, post to a photo sharing site and make a link here please.

Comment: Hi Andiih, Here is the link.In clear as seen in the image I want to develop images with numbers on it in the same way as seen in this image.the way I ask question may be wrong.I am sorry for that.But you can see what I want in this link.

http://www.textually.org/textually/archives/2010/04/09/twitter.jpeg

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is it possible to develop any image manually as shown in the link?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the other answer, "I want to know weather is it possible to create images with numbers in that particular format just as we see in twitter site.":

I'm going to take a guess that you mean the number "buttons" in the top right corner of Twitter:
[twitter format? http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/6308/twitterbuttons.png](http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/6308/twitterbuttons.png)

If so, these aren't images. They're numbers. It's HTML. Here is the HTML for one button:

```
<a href="/following" id="following_count_link" class="link-following_page" rel="me" title="See who you’re following">
  <span id="following_count" class="stats_count numeric">29 </span>
  <span class="label">Following</span>
</a>
```

Sorry if this was a wrong guess; just taking a stab at the dark.

Comment: Hi Ricket,
Thanks for the response.But I want to know weather is it possible to develop images as seen in this link?

http://www.textually.org/textually/archives/2010/04/09/twitter.jpeg

Thanks,

Comment: @Adusum: it would be better to edit your question (or add comments there) to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: Welp, this gets my vote for most terrible question ever. Also not programming related, though I don't have the rep to vote as such.

Answer (score 0):

The link http://www.textually.org/textually/archives/2010/04/09/twitter.jpeg you supply points to the word Twitter. It is in the font Pico. The iphone does not have Pico as a built in font, so if you want to write (well draw) in that font, you need to make an image with all the letters you may need, then pick them using an offset into the image.

However, I'm still not convinced this is an answer to your question!

Comment: K Thankyou.Let me try the way you told.
I will update furthur after working on it.